# Compiler failed with error code - missing assembly found, but why is it missing

Tags: asp.net, .net, iis-7.5, windows-server-2008-r2

After analysis, I have the following error:

```
C0150004    STATUS_SXS_ASSEMBLY_NOT_FOUND
```

I went through the entire list of files called by the compiler (ie. `C:\Windows\SysWOW64\inetsrv> "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v3.5\csc.exe"...`

The only file that didn't exist is in bold

> /R:"C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.ServiceModel\3.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.ServiceModel.dll" /out:**"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files\applications_my_app\e34a7fe0\b4388432\en\App_GlobalResources.snrifx3y.resources.dll"** /D:DEBUG /debug+ /optimize-

In **DEV** and **TEST**, the corresponding file exists.

This site is `.Net 2.0`, `Classic App Pool`.

I've compared as much as I can between the environments where this works, but can't seem to find anything that would hint at why this isn't working in **PROD**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The machine was seriously corrupted and had to be rebuilt.